# Git push heroku master --Enter passphrase for key

Tags: heroku, ssh-keys, heroku-toolbelt

I'm managing multiple heroku accounts and have had to struggle through getting multiple keys added.  I've finally done it and I feel confident that I have the correct keys for the correct accounts.

Now, I can push to the first account fine but the second gives me `Enter passphrase for key '~/.ssh/key.pub'` when I didn't set a passphrase.  I tried `heroku keys:clear` multiple times and re-added keys, both with and without passphrases.  When I do enter a passphrase, it gives me three chances and then failed with `Permission denied (publickey)`.  When I just enter because the passphrase is empty it goes immediately to `Permission denied (publickey)`.

It may also be noteworthy that the original key was created by heroku and it does not prompt for a passphrase.  I've tried generating the account with  `heroku accounts:add personal --auto` as described in the accounts plugin for heroku [here](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts) and it fails with a `No such file or directory - ~/.ssh/identity.heroku.personal.pub` when `Adding public key to Heroku account: account@gmail.com`.

My .ssh/config looks like the following:

```
Host heroku.personal
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile "~/.ssh/key.pub"
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host heroku.ad2l
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile "~/.ssh/another_key.pub"
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance.